# How to make filter toolbar in JQGrid case insensitive and set a place holder in it?

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid

Sometimes I was not getting some small things easily.

Today my problem is I am using JQgrid in that I was using filter toolbar to search.

It is working fine, but what I need is that search is only doing with case sensitive.

Example:"A"

If I give it is showing Result Antony. But if I give "a" its not showing anything how to I make it case in sensitive.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var lastsel3;
    var cl;
    var a = new Date();
    var QColName = a.getFullYear();
    var Q4ColName = (a.getFullYear()) + 1;
    var json_string = document.getElementById("hdntxt").value;

    if (json_string.length > 0) {
        var search_result = $.parseJSON(json_string);
    }
    jQuery("#gvLockHistory").jqGrid({
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        height: 'auto',
        width: '480',
        gridview: true,
        datatype: "local",
        data: search_result,
        colNames: ['Type', 'Month', 'Action'],
        colModel: [
        { name: 'LockType', index: 'LockType', editable: false, sortable: true, align: 'center',width:158 },
        { name: 'MonthYearStringValue', index: 'MonthYearStringValue', editable: false, sortable: false, align: 'center', width: 157 },
        { name: 'IsActive', index: 'IsActive', editable: true, align: 'center', sortable: false, search: false, width: 150 }
        ],
        rowNum: 8,
        pager: '#pager',
        rowList: [8, 10, 20, 30],
        multipleSearch: true,
        multipleGroup: true,
        shrinkToFit: false,
        viewrecords: true,
        caseSensitive: false,
        sortorder: "desc",
        //editurl: "server.php",
        gridComplete: function () {
            var ids = jQuery("#gvLockHistory").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
            for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                cl = ids[i];
                //be = "<input class='btn btn-mini' type='button' value='Unlock' onclick=\"unlock('" + cl + "');\"  />";
                be = "<input class='btn btn-mini' type='button' value='Unlock' onclick=\"unlock('" + cl + "');\"  />";
                jQuery("#gvLockHistory").jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], { IsActive: be });

            }
        }
    });
```

This is i was search in net to make case insensitive but its not working

```
    $("#gvLockHistory").filterToolbar({ stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false,defaultSearch:"cn"});


});
```

Please help me thanks in advance. And please don't forget about the place holder which need to display in filter section.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you are using a relatively new version of jqgrid you can set the following option to make the search case insensitive:

```
ignoreCase: true
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks its working and how can i set a place holder inside the search in JQgrid

Comment: It is not working in jqGrid  3.7.2   Kindly help for alternate solution.

Answer (score 13):

You need to set `ignoreCase: true` in jqGrid options. The answer by @f01 did not work for me. I am using jqGrid version 4.6.0.

```
grid.jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    editurl: 'clientArray',
    caption: "Values",
    ignoreCase: true, //By default the local searching is case-sensitive. 
                      //To make the local search and sorting not 
                      //case-insensitive set this options to true

    colNames: ["", "", ""],
    colModel: [{
        name: "value",
        // .. more stuff
});
```